# le soir/au soir/ce soir/dans la soiree

Tags: vocabulaire

Est-ce que *le soir* ça veut dire tous les soirs comme avec *le samedi* ?

Est-ce qu’on peut dire

> On peut faire du shopping et le soir on peut aller dans un resto.

pour indiquer un plan pour un rendez-vous  ou est-ce qu‘il faut utiliser *au soir/ce soir* ?

Ça fonctionne aussi avec *dans la soirée* ?

> On peut faire du shopping et dans la soirée on peut aller dans un resto.

Est-qu‘il y a une différence entre les deux?

Comment: **ce soir** désigne aujourd'hui, **le soir** ne définit pas de temporalité précise (sauf si précisé avant dans la phrase)

Comment: C'est hors-sujet, mais on préfèrera "aller au resto". 
"Aller dans un resto" serait comparable à l'anglais "To go inside a restaurant" où on préfèrerait "To go to the restaurant".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ce n'est pas incorrect, mais "le samedi" ou "le soir" sera utilisé si on parle de façon générale. Par exemple :

> Quand je suis en vacances en Espagne j'aime faire du shopping et sortir le soir.

Si on parle d'aujourd'hui, on dira plutôt :

> On peut faire du shopping maintenant, et ce soir aller au resto.

Si on dit "et le soir aller au resto", c'est correct également, mais personnellement je trouve que ça sonne moins bien. En français il est habituel d'utiliser "ce matin", "ce midi", "ce soir", "cette nuit".

Si je parle de quelque chose qui s'est passé ce matin, je dirai "ce matin j'ai glissé sur une peau de banane". On n'entendra pas souvent "Le matin j'ai glissé sur une peau de banane", c'est comme si cela laissait planer un doute, parle-t-on bien de ce matin ? Car on pourrait dire "Mercredi passé j'ai eu une grosse surprise, le matin j'ai glissé sur une peau de banane." Quand on utilise "ce matin" ou "ce soir" il n'y a aucun doute qu'on parle d'aujourd'hui.

"Dans la soirée" peut remplacer "ce soir", mais tout le monde ne comprend pas ces expressions de la même façon. Dans la soirée peut être une période assez longue qui commence quand le soleil va bientôt se coucher, et pour moi le soir est plutôt synonyme de quand il fera noir. Mais c'est un détail, les deux expressions peuvent être utilisées.

Il y a un bon article ici sur l'utilisation de soir / soirée, car il y a quelques rares cas où on ne peut utiliser que "soir" : https://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/vocabulaire/difference-soir-soiree-nuit.html

Mais pour ton rendez-vous, je pense que le plus simple est le mieux :

"On peut faire du shopping maintenant et aller au resto ce soir ?"

Comment: Merci, et si je fais des plans pour le week-end. Je utiliserai « ce soir-là » ou une autre expression ?

Comment: Le problème avec "week-end" c'est que ça représente plusieurs jours, si on dit "Nous irons au resto ce weekend", on ne sait pas si on parle du samedi ou du dimanche, midi ou soir. Même si on dit "ce soir-là" il y a un doute sur le samedi ou le dimanche (ou même le vendredi). Mais si on parle d'un jour précis, par exemple "Le jour de l'An, on ira chez mes parents et le soir on dormira à l'hôtel" c'est correct.

Comment: Mais pour revenir au week-end, le plus habituel sera de préciser le jour. Ensuite on peut utiliser "ce jour-là" pour ne pas se répéter : "Je te propose d'aller au resto dimanche soir. Ce jour-là il y a généralement moins de monde."